# Jupyter notebook on github renders a paragraph mark

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I have some jupyter notebooks that are rendered weird on github, as you can see [here](https://github.com/andreeas26/TSM_UNetSegmentation/blob/master/evaluate.ipynb) or in the screenshot below
[image: screenshot]

I think it has something to do with line endings LF/CRLF because when I add them for a commit  got the following warning:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in evaluate.ipynb.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

However setting core.autocrlf to false with `git config --global core.autocrlf false` did not help.

I only want that the notebooks are displayed correctly on the github since on my laptop I don't have any issue. I don't think is a problem on Github's side or the browser since I can see other jupyter notebooks rendered correctly. Could you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: There are more issues than the paragraph symbol (lack of syntax highlight etc). It is known for some time that Colab ignores the notebook standard/uses well outdated nbformat version. You could try to convert it to a newer version with nbconvert.

Comment: For example, compare [your notebook in raw mode](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreeas26/TSM_UNetSegmentation/master/evaluate.ipynb) with [with this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp/master/examples/Python.ipynb) (which renders correctly).

Comment: I tried nbconvert. Did not worked. [link](https://github.com/andreeas26/TSM_UNetSegmentation/blob/master/train.ipynb) But it's strange that not all notebooks in the repository were create using Colab. For example all in the data_analysis folder were create outside of Colab and they still render weird.

Comment: Those marks are probably meant to be clickable / copyable links directly to that portion of the documentation. For instance, the Go documentation (e.g., at https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) does the same thing, except that the ¶ symbol only pops up while you are near the header line. (But note, this has nothing to do with Git itself.)

Comment: @torek Ok...and how I get rid of them? :)) I just want them to render as a jupyter notebook renders usually.

Comment: No idea - if I knew I would have posted an answer, I'm just observing what the likely intent is. GitHub markdown seems to have inserted them on its own and I don't know where or why that might happen.

Comment: @torek. You're right about the link. In jupyterlab the  ¶ symbol only pops ups near markdown headlines. But somehow on github is permanent and it also ruins the overall rendering of the notebook. Do you think it would be better to post an issue on github side?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that either. I have not seen these link markers pop up before and have not been reading any github blogs that might explain what they're doing, why, when particular features might be turned on or adjusted, etc.

Comment: Now it renders fine. Maybe it was really an issue from github. I don't know. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions!